# Hook a function with binary instrumentation

Tags: c++, c, linux, hook, instrumentation

I need to write a code which it let me monitor functions which called by an executable via American Fuzzer Lop and Qemu.

But I don't know how can I do that! is that possible to hook a function in binary instrumentation process and monitor the function calling process? after a function called I get the result of the calling in another log file.

Comment: You should be able to do it. My best guess would be to look into adding DTRACE/SystemTap instrumentation points

Comment: Are there any example for that? i

Comment: I wrote a post a while back on implementing Instrumentation points. My purpose was to gain low-level statistics, but it should contain give you a feel for the possibilities and point you towards some good resources: https://dekker.one/post/dtrace/

Comment: What's an American fuzzer? Do you do it with your clothes on, or off ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is so called "API hooking"

Windows :

search for "[detour](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/)", microsoft c++ api hooking library

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours

[How to use the Detour library in C++ properly for a simple hook of a function with known memory adress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989429/how-to-use-the-detour-library-in-c-properly-for-a-simple-hook-of-a-function-wi)

[general idea and usage](https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c/72416-simplest-function-hooking-ida-detours-and-c.html)

also this can be useful : [MinHook](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra)

Linux :

http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2014/09/05/how-to-wrap-a-system-call-libc-function-in-linux/

https://github.com/Zeex/subhook

http://opensourceforu.com/2011/08/lets-hook-a-library-function/

https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/hooking-functions-in-linux-and-or-osx

https://blog.netspi.com/function-hooking-part-i-hooking-shared-library-function-calls-in-linux/

Comment: Isn't Detour Windows-only? On Linux, to hook some **particular** functions one need to just compile a .so file with overriding functions (they can retrieve the original ones to delegate some work to them) and specify it using the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, but I'm not sure how `qemu-user` handles this var and what it will then instrument for AFL if it will work. But this approach does not handles tracing **all** invoked functions.